# How to run tkinker while I have a different loop running

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

So in my program I'm using tkinter to handle my key presses 
However my program runs in a tick loop and I've found out that my programs tick loop and tkinters main loop are clashing with eatch other. Is there a way to fix this? Dose tkinter have a function that dose a single loop that I could call on eatch of my ticks?
If not then what would you recommend replacing tkinter with to handle key pressing?

Comment: Do root.update at each tick.  I have done this to mix tkinter event handling with asyncio loop

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with the same issue :)

You can achieve what you want using `tkinter`'s `after()` and `after_idle()` functions.

For example, a `loop` function can look like that:

```
def loop(self):
    #  do whatever your tick loop needs to to
    self.cyclesId = self.after_idle(self.loop)
```

You can call it only once and it will be called again every iteration of `tkinter`'s `mainloop()`.